# Spring Open JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jboss5.x, openjpa

I am trying to integrate Spring and OpenJpa. For every scenario the exception thrown is 
    **SAXParseException: No Content allowed in Prolog.**
I am aware that the issue is probably related to the xml files but all the related xmls are read and validated correctly. The spring files are parsed correctly and beans are created but the entitymanager creation fails and the root exception is this content not allowed in prolog error. I am not sure which are the relevant sections to post here. If required I can post the full contents of the files. I have further isolated that this problem comes up after I am adding a class tag entry to persistence.xml. Can anyone please help me on this? I am posting the fuul stacktrace:

```
**11:39:45,931 INFO  [STDOUT] jpa template is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate@649a07
  11:39:45,981 ERROR [STDERR] 3215  idea  INFO   [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.1
  11:39:47,293 ERROR [STDERR] 4527  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Using metadata factory "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.PersistenceMappingFactory@99abd7".
  11:39:48,294 ERROR [STDERR] 5528  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning URL "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/" for persistent types.
  11:39:48,304 ERROR [STDERR] 5538  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scan of "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/" found persistent types [Ljava.lang.String;@a92583.
  11:39:48,304 ERROR [STDERR] 5538  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Mapping resource location "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/" to persistent types "[]".
  11:39:48,304 ERROR [STDERR] 5538  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning resource "mappings.xml" for persistent types.
  11:39:48,314 ERROR [STDERR] 5548  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scan of "mappings.xml" found persistent types [Ljava.lang.String;@16e3879.
  11:39:48,314 ERROR [STDERR] 5548  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Mapping resource location "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/mappings.xml" to persistent types "[com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ActivityData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.EventData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.GroupData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ProductData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ReportData]".
  11:39:48,314 ERROR [STDERR] 5548  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning resource "META-INF/orm.xml" for persistent types.
  11:39:48,324 ERROR [STDERR] 5558  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - parsePersistentTypeNames() found [com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.GroupData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ActivityData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.EventData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ReportData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ProductData].
  11:39:48,324 ERROR [STDERR] 5558  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Found 5 classes with metadata in 30 milliseconds.
  11:39:48,365 ERROR [STDERR] 5599  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Using metadata factory "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.PersistenceMappingFactory@1ee33fd".
  11:39:48,365 ERROR [STDERR] 5599  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Loading metadata for "class com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.GroupData" under mode "[META][QUERY]".
  11:39:48,365 ERROR [STDERR] 5599  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning URL "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/" for persistent types.
  11:39:48,375 ERROR [STDERR] 5609  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scan of "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/" found persistent types [Ljava.lang.String;@f9daf2.
  11:39:48,375 ERROR [STDERR] 5609  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Mapping resource location "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/" to persistent types "[]".
  11:39:48,375 ERROR [STDERR] 5609  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning resource "mappings.xml" for persistent types.
  11:39:48,385 ERROR [STDERR] 5619  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scan of "mappings.xml" found persistent types [Ljava.lang.String;@3e68dc.
  11:39:48,385 ERROR [STDERR] 5619  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Mapping resource location "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/mappings.xml" to persistent types "[com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ActivityData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.EventData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.GroupData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ProductData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ReportData]".
  11:39:48,385 ERROR [STDERR] 5619  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Scanning resource "META-INF/orm.xml" for persistent types.
  11:39:48,395 ERROR [STDERR] 5629  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - parsePersistentTypeNames() found [com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.GroupData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ActivityData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.EventData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ReportData, com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ProductData].
  11:39:48,395 ERROR [STDERR] 5629  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Found 5 classes with metadata in 30 milliseconds.
  11:39:48,685 ERROR [STDERR] 5919  idea  TRACE  [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] openjpa.MetaData - Parsing resource "vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/".
  11:39:48,785 ERROR [lifecycle] JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /queueDetails.jsp) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@155c746]
  11:39:48,785 ERROR [[FacesServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
  org.xml.sax.SAXException: vfsfile:/D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sandeep.kumar.aggarw/Desktop/Desktop/Software/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/IdeaWebappDev.war/WEB-INF/classes/ [Location: Line: 1, C: 1]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at       org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.getException(XMLMetaDataParser.java:656)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.fatalError(XMLMetaDataParser.java:421)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parseNewResource(XMLMetaDataParser.java:376)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:318)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:295)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:268)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory.parseXML(PersistenceMetaDataFactory.java:247)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory.load(PersistenceMetaDataFactory.java:198)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:474)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:294)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.getMapping(MappingRepository.java:285)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.getMapping(MappingTool.java:676)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.buildSchema(MappingTool.java:748)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.run(MappingTool.java:646)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:153)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:189)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:434)
at $Proxy125.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:195)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:142)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.getTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:129)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:174)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.executeFind(JpaTemplate.java:151)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.find(JpaTemplate.java:311)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.find(JpaTemplate.java:307)
at com.idea.app.dataservice.DataQueueServiceImpl.getQueueRecords(DataQueueServiceImpl.java:79)
at com.idea.app.dataservice.DataQueueServiceImpl.getQueueDetails(DataQueueServiceImpl.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy127.getQueueDetails(Unknown Source)
at com.idea.app.business.BusinessQueueServiceImpl.getQueueDetails(BusinessQueueServiceImpl.java:34)
at com.idea.app.bean.QueueBeanHelper.getSavedRecords(QueueBeanHelper.java:76)
at com.idea.app.bean.QueueDetailsBean.fetchData(QueueDetailsBean.java:150)
at com.idea.app.bean.QueueDetailsBean.<init>(QueueDetailsBean.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:222)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:101)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:184)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:201)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:284)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:154)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:696)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:667)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This is my mapping xml:

```
        <id name="prdRecordId">
            <column name="PRD_RECORD_ID" nullable="false" />
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
        </id>
        <basic name="productId">
            <column name="PRODUCT_ID"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="productGroupid">
            <column name="PRODUCT_GROUPID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="empGroupclassificationCode">
            <column name="EMP_GROUPCLASSIFICATION_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="empGroupclassificationId">
            <column name="EMP_GROUPCLASSIFICATION_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productName">
            <column name="PRODUCT_NAME" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productType">
            <column name="PRODUCT_TYPE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="prodEffdate">
            <column name="PROD_EFFDATE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="prodTermdate">
            <column name="PROD_TERMDATE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="prodDescription">
            <column name="PROD_DESCRIPTION" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="prodShortDescription">
            <column name="PROD_SHORT_DESCRIPTION" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="priorInd">
            <column name="PRIOR_IND" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="prodBusinessUnitCode">
            <column name="PROD_BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="calculationMethodCode">
            <column name="CALCULATION_METHOD_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="pairedGroupNumber">
            <column name="PAIRED_GROUP_NUMBER" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="coverageCode">
            <column name="COVERAGE_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="fundingType">
            <column name="FUNDING_TYPE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="prodSubtypeValue">
            <column name="PROD_SUBTYPE_VALUE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="packageCode">
            <column name="PACKAGE_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="billRef">
            <column name="BILL_REF" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="billSortOrderCode">
            <column name="BILL_SORT_ORDER_CODE" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="employeeClassId">
            <column name="EMPLOYEE_CLASS_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="productCategory">
            <column name="PRODUCT_CATEGORY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="benefitPlanId">
            <column name="BENEFIT_PLAN_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="contibutory">
            <column name="CONTRIBUTORY" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="benefitClassId">
            <column name="BENEFIT_CLASS_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="benefitClassText">
            <column name="BENEFIT_CLASS_TEXT" />
        </basic>
        <many-to-one name="groupId"
            target-entity="com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.GroupData" fetch="LAZY">
            <join-column name="GROUP_ID"   nullable="false" />
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </many-to-one>
    </attributes>
</entity>
<entity class="com.idea.app.dataservice.dto.ReportData" name="ReportData">
    <table name="REPORT_LOG" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="reportId">
            <column name="REPORT_ID" nullable="false" />
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
        </id>
        <basic name="brndTxt">
            <column name="BRND_TXT"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="bsnsUntCd">
            <column name="BSNS_UNT_CD" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="srcSysCd">
            <column name="SRC_SYS_CD" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="scrbrId">
            <column name="SCRBR_ID" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="mbrNmeTxt">
            <column name="MBR_NME_TXT" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="trnsTyp">
            <column name="TRNS_TYP" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="trnsSts">
            <column name="TRNS_STS" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="processTier">
            <column name="PROCESS_TIER" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="erroMsg">
            <column name="ERRO_MSG" />
        </bas
```

Comment: If you can't figure out what is going on, I'd suggest posting this question to the OpenJPA users mailing list / forum [1].

-Rick

[1] http://n2.nabble.com/OpenJPA-Users-f208411.html

Comment: Which JBoss AS version?
Did you build or downloaded the binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the source and your stack trace (looking at source code can reveal a lot) it seems to be that one of your xml mapping files is where the problem lies.

If you turn on openjpa.MetaData to TRACE level you will see in which file it occurs.

I *think* you do this by specifying openjpa.Log=openjpa.MetaData=TRACE as a property... though I'm not sure since I specify this via spring and not plain jpa.

It will tell you what file it is processing when the error occurs though I suspect you won't find anything wrong that you can see and there will be strange characters (that you can't see) in the "prolog".

Comment: @Michael
Hi after setting the openjpa.MetaData to TRACE level I got the logs but still am unable to locate the issue as it is not giving a specific file name but generally referring to the classes folder as a whole. I have updated my post with the updated error log and also my mapping.xml. Can you help me on this?

Comment: sounds like you need to add the open jpa source, run the system in debug mode and put break points close to where it falls over so you can see what it is doing.

Comment: i am currently doing that trying to run in debug mode. But strangely the same war file with the same xmls is working fine in Websphere 7. But in JBoss 5 this error is coming. Now while we use Websphere in production we use JBoss on developer machines. So it needs to work on both the environments. What can be different in the two servers?

Comment: I share your pain. We did the same thing, dev on jboss, deploy on WAS and there were a handful of instances where they behaved differently! In this case, it probably has something to do with classpath/classloaders in jboss and websphere.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so stack trace doesn't specify the actual file name but it looks like one of OpenJPA mapping files.

"No Content allowed in Prolog" exception is usually thrown when there's anything in xml file prior to `<?xml` declaration - you'll need to look through your files and make sure that's not the case.

Another possible issue that has been known to cause this is when xml encoding is specified as "utf-16" (certain XML tools like to do that). Changing it back to "utf-8" tends to resolve the problem.

Comment: @ChssPly76
I dont have the xml files with me right now to post but I have already tried out these options. <?xml are the first characters in the file and I also use utf-8 and also tried removing it. Actually I tried removing the property tags for the persistence unit so as to see if it could parse the xml and point out the missing information. It did. I found out that if I remove the class entry froom persistence unit this error does not come up. I will post the xml files at the earliest.

Comment: So you're saying that if you remove one particular class entry from persistence.xml, everything works (well, the class is not getting mapped but I this error doesn't occur)? Perhaps there's something weird is going on with that specific class? Stack trace looks as if repository were trying to obtain metadata for that class but couldn't do it via annotations and was looking for XML version in /WEB-INF/classes...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this recently with JBoss AS 5. The problem was that some component was trying to access a XML file through the VFS (virtual file system), but the path given was a directory. So instead of SAXParser exception, FileNotFound should be thrown.

Check your config, something causes that the wrong path is given to the SAXParser.